# GCP CloudSQL Access from same GCP Project without Proxy

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm totally stumped on what I think is probably something easy. Been searching for days on this with no luck as I learn how to use Cloud SQL. There are lots of examples on app engine, but almost none on the simplicity of connecting a GCP Virtual Machine to GCP Cloud SQL. The instructions from Google don't seem to be complete. Here is what I have:

In the same GCP Project I created a Bitnami LAMP VM. In the same project I've created a CloudSQL Instance with a single database, and two tables. My intent is to experiment with accessing CloudSQL via a PHP script from the VM. (Yes I know I could setup an SQL server on the VM, but my intent here is to learn how to access CloudSQL). Note, everything is in the same GCP project, so from what I can understand I should NOT have to use the SQL proxy.

I've enabled the CloudSQL API in the project as well.

```
<?php
$DB_NAME = "dwelling_winebot";
$DB_USER = "winebot_reader";
$DB_PASS = "winebot_reader";
$tableName = "wines";
$mysqli = new mysqli(null, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME,null, "/cloudsql/web-sites-123456:us-central1:winebot");

... More code below
```

The error I get in the apache error_log is:

```
[08-Oct-2018 05:00:24 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  mysqli::__constru
ct(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdo
cs/winebot/serverside/inforunner.php on line 25
```

(Incidentally, line 25 is the $mysqli line and the php filename is inforunner.php that has the php code above )

Notable facts:

- I CAN see the database instance if I run "gcloud sql instances
  describe winebot"

  - I have created a user named winebot_reader... Saying this I also tried 'root' with a "" password as some documents
    suggested. No luck.
  - The cloudsql instance name is infact the right project name, zone, and database from the console.
  - I do not seem to have a local /cloudsql folder with socket paths as some documents suggest I should have?
  - According to the console, the CloudSQL API is turned on
  - In the location field of the mysqli call (first parameter) I have tried, null, localhost, 127.0.0.1. All with the same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the internal IP instead of a socket, which does not exist.

see [Connecting MySQL Client from Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-compute-engine) for reference.

Comment: Wow! That was stunningly easy. So I used a PRIVATE IP (beta), and completely removed the socket reference and it worked.  So, why do the Google instructions enforce the use of the socket address? Just curious. Either way, it totally works now. Thanks!

Comment: @mumcs01 UNIX domain sockets are for inter-process communication on the same host - which barely would be the case with CloudSQL (as a managed service on another host).